# BrowserViz error when trying to run RCyjs example

Tags: r, cytoscape.js

Trying to test out the [RCyjs](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/RCyjs/inst/doc/RCyjs.pdf) package because I want to learn about using [Cytospace.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/) within R/Shiny apps. However, I run the following:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("RCyjs")
library(RCyjs)

g <- simpleDemoGraph()
noaNames(g)
edaNames(g)
noa(g, "type")
noa(g, "lfc")
eda(g, "edgeType")
eda(g, "score")
g <- simpleDemoGraph()
rcy <- RCyjs(portRange=9047:9067, quiet=TRUE, graph=g);
title <- "simple graph"
setBrowserWindowTitle(rcy, title)
```

which is the installation, and the first example from the RCyjs vignette. I get this error:

> Error in file.exists(browserFile) :    argument "browserFile" is
>   missing, with no default

on the RCyjs(...) line.

Anyone have any suggestions? Not sure where to go when even the tutorials don't seem to work.

Comment: Will get to this embarrassing bug today, with a fix by Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in both the devel (2.3.6) and release version (2.2.1) available from github.  The Bioconductor build system will complete its daily round soon as well after which `biocLite("RCyjs")` will install a fixed version.

```
git clone git@git.bioconductor.org:packages/RCyjs
cd RCyjs
R CMD INSTALL .
```

Your bug report is a wake-up call, motivating a rethinking of our approach to automated testing.   Testing for browser-based packages was once part of the Bioconductor build process, but is no longer.  Max sensibly proposes travis/ci integrated with github commits.  I should have done this months ago.

Comment: Thanks for the update Paul. Feel free to close my Github issue as well

Comment: Will do, Kyle.   Thanks for reporting the bug.    Are you interested in contributing to a Shiny widget for cytoscape.js?   We are just about to reinvigorate that project, idle for a few years now, and probably following the API shared by RCyjs and RCy3.   The latter package has just been taken over by the Cytoscape core team, adding some very fine features.   Let me know if you would like to be involved!